# Why .gitignore files are appearing in master while they are ignored in development branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, gitignore, git-checkout

I have a development branch, where in one of the sub-directories I created a .gitignore file, added the file(s) to be ignored, committed and pushed the change to development branch. But now when I checkout to master (because I want to merge development to master), the ignored files show up as unstaged changes. Why does it happen this way? What am I doing wrong in the workflow? How can I fix it? (I am using VS code for my work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are untracked, so Git will not touch them when you change branches.

The development branch has a .gitignore, so they are ignored when development is checked out. When you checkout master the untracked files are still there, but there is no .gitignore file; they show up as untracked.

Merge development into master. Then master will have the .gitignore file and they will be ignored.

Comment: thank you so much for such an easy explanation. I tried finding about it earlier but couldn't. Thanks again.